# Whats going on here can't you compare if(mychar1 == 'ä' || mychar2 == 'Ä') in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

Im trying to compare these two chars but on win 32 Visual Studio 2008:

```
if(mychar1 ==  'ä'  || mychar2 == 'Ä')
```

Erromess:

Debug Assertion Failed!

File:f\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\xstring
Line 1575

Expression: string subscript out of range

Comment: We need to see at least how mychar1 and mychar2 are defined...

Comment: ok its a little bit complicated, they are sent as arguments after have been lowercased:
std::transform(string2.begin(), string2.end(),string2.begin(),std::tolower);//string3 as well
if(caseTrue(string2[0] ,string3[0]))
..
caseTrue(char mychar1, char mychar2){
if(mychar1 ==  'ä'  || mychar2 == 'Ä')

Comment: I edited my answer so that it refers to this code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works on my machine:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char mychar1, mychar2;
    std::cin >> mychar1 >> mychar2;
    if(!std::cin)
        return 2;
    if(mychar1 ==  'ä' || mychar2 == 'Ä' )
       return 1;
    std::cout << "No!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the error you quote ("string subscript out of range") implies that you try to access a character in a string at an invalid index. Something like `my_str.at(10)` (or, in a Debug build, `my_str[10]`), where `my_str` only has 10 characters. Since the code you showed doesn't access characters in strings, the error is in code you don't show.

***Edit***: The code you showed in a comment to your question *does* access characters in a string using `operator[]()`. When you do `string2[0]`, have you checked that the string isn't empty?

Comment: Make sure that your file (.cpp) is saved as ASCII or iso-8859-15 / iso-latin9, not UTF-8 or somesuch.